# How to check the current schemas and change the default schema in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write queries in Oracle. I wanted to make sure it worked with the correct schema, so I thought the below code would solve my issue.  I guess syntax is wrong.

Could you fix it?

```
DECLARE
  v_current_schema varchar2(30);
BEGIN
  v_current_schema := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA');
  IF V_CURRENT_SCHEMA <> 'PRODUCTION' THEN
    ALTER  SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = "PRODUCTION" ;
  END IF;
END;
```

---

```
ORA-06550: row 6, column 13:PLS-00103: Encountered symbol "ALTER", expected one of the following:( start report status go to exit if loop mod empty pragma remove back select update while with <determinant>
```

Comment: PL/SQL has no `alter` keyword. However I'm not sure why you can't just issue the `alter session` directly on the command line. Why do you need to know the current schema first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things

- `DDL` commands must run always by `execute immediate` in PL/SQL.
- You don't need the variable at all, as you can use `sys_context` directly inside the `if-then` statement.

Code simplified

```
declare
begin
  if sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA') <> 'PRODUCTION' 
  then
     execute immediate 'ALTER  SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = PRODUCTION ' ;
  end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is dynamic SQL you should use:

```
declare
v_current_schema varchar2(30);
begin
  v_current_schema := sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA');
  if v_current_schema <> 'PRODUCTION' then
     execute immediate 'ALTER  SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = PRODUCTION' ;
  end if ; 
end; 
/
```